# Clear a Look Up column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-activity

I have a lookup field, that has some value initially. This lookup field; lookup1; allows multiple values. Using workflow 2010 and 2013, how can I delete the values in this lookup1. Just simply set it to null, just as if nothing was selected.

Things I have done are the following:

Created a new lookup column; lookup2;  exactly like lookup1, but it is always set to have no value, it is hidden. then I would update or set the field lookup1 to lookup2. The workflow gets suspended due to an error.

Set or update the lookup1 to 0. The workflow gets suspended due to an error.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first solution, and set the return fields as "Lookup Values,Comma Delimited":

[image]